# How to connect the dots with a line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I was able to plot the dots from an image. I am now trying to connect the dots using a line. Essentially mimicking those connect the dot puzzles.

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

original_image = Image.open("jg.jpg") 
bw_image = original_image.convert('1') 

bw_image_array = np.array(bw_image, dtype=np.int)  
black_indices = np.argwhere(bw_image_array == 0)  
chosen_black_indices = black_indices[np.random.choice(black_indices.shape[0], replace=False, size=90000)]  

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)  
plt.scatter([x[1] for x in chosen_black_indices], [x[0] for x in chosen_black_indices], color='black', s=1)  
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  
plt.xticks([])  
plt.yticks([]) 
plt.show()
```

I am aiming for this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random_sample(size=100)
y = np.random.random_sample(size=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
plt.show()
```

I am struggling with what would go inside of `plt.plot()` in order to connect the dots of the image.

Comment: _I am struggling with what would go inside of `plt.plot()` in order to connect the dots of the image._ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the answer there in your second code block. [Matplotlib's plot function](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) can handle plotting connected points with the `marker='o'` argument, so you don't need to call scatter at all. So just change this line:

```
plt.scatter([x[1] for x in chosen_black_indices],
            [x[0] for x in chosen_black_indices],
            color='black', s=1)
```

to this:

```
plt.plot([x[1] for x in chosen_black_indices],
         [x[0] for x in chosen_black_indices],
         marker='o',
         color='black')
```